# How to size resources (CPUs, RAM, etc) for AWS MySQL database?

Tags: memory, cpu, mysql, amazon-web-services

In a production environment, 20K scans (records) will uploaded to the AWS database in a day: assume no more than 10K in an hour.  A record consists of 6 fields and approximately 50 bytes of data.

```
1) Is there a method to estimate the correct sizing (selection) of AWS CPUs & RAM?
2) Are any other inputs needed to size AWS resources?
```

Any lessons-learned and pitfalls to avoid are always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, and definitely not from what you've told us. It depends if you're using [Relational Database Service](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/), [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/), EC2 instances with a relational database software installed, and what you do with the data.

The best thing to do is benchmark the instance with your workload. If you do that consider using spot instances, perhaps [booking the spot instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-requests.html#fixed-duration-spot-instances) for a period of time so you don't lose the spot instance.

Things to be careful of if you install software on an instance:

- If you use a [t2 instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html) (and you should consider them as they're cheap and capable) running out of CPU credits. You can go to a larger t2 size of course.
- EBS running out of [burst credits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html). Unlikely in your case with low volume.